# How to resolve error on request.login() after including resteasy multipart provider?

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, wildfly, java-ee-7

### Background

I have a java ee 7 application using wildfly 8.2.0.Final as the application server. I have come across [this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/using-rest-services-to-manage-download-and-upload-of-files) article outlining the process in which to create a restful file uploading service.

The aim of the project is to be able to upload videos and images to the site via a web and mobile (ios/android) app. The user will need to be authenticated to use the service. I have managed to configure the server and java servlet to handle login and logouts, I then wanted to work on a restful back end to expose some of the business logic. After following that site and including the resteasy multipart provider in my pom.xml the request.login() and request.logout() functions has some error associated with them. The only details netbeans gives when I hover over the red explanation mark is:

> cannot find symbol
>
> symbol: method logout()
>
> location: variable request of type HttpServletRequest

### Problem

Including resteasy-multipart-provider results in request.login and request.logout() giving a cannot find symbol error.

Answer (score 2):

Check the version of the Servlet API you're compiling against. `logout()` was introduced in 3.0. Using 2.5 or older would cause the compiler error you're seeing.

Comment: I assume (from what I've scouted around on the net for) that you can determine the Servlet API from the web.xml file. My <web-app version="3.1" ...> Plus it doesn't quite explain why it would work when I don't include the multipart provider in maven and vice versa.